# Taking 10 to 15 mins of time for this code block to run in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

Code:

```
FuturesPosition[] positionarray = positions.ToArray();
int arrayLenth = positionarray.Length;
int bestmask = -1;
double best = 0;
for (int mask = 0; mask < Math.Pow(3, arrayLenth); ++mask)
{
    double tradeable = TradeableCash - getPositionNotional("OFWP");
    for (int p = 0, div, offset; p < arrayLenth; ++p)
    {
        var position = positionarray[p];
        div = (int)Math.Pow(3, p);
        offset = ((mask / div) % 3) - 1;
        if (position.getHedge() > 0 && position.getPosition("OFWP") + offset > 0)
        {
            tradeable -= offset * position.FutureNotional;
        }
    }
    if (bestmask < 0 || Math.Abs(tradeable) < best)
    {
        bestmask = mask;
        best = Math.Abs(tradeable);
    }
}
for (int p = 0, div, offset; p < arrayLenth; ++p)
{
    div = (int)Math.Pow(3, p);
    offset = ((bestmask / div) % 3) - 1;
    var position = positionarray[p];
    if (position.getHedge() > 0 && position.getPosition("OFWP") + offset > 0)
    {
        position.adjustPending(offset);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well...that's a mess you posted there.  Nobody is going to bother to read that in a literal "block format".

Comment: How about you run it through a profiler and see where most of the time gets taken up?  A nested for loop is bound to be resource intensive to begin with.  A plain English description of what the algorithm is doing might be helpful for others to understand it and make an intelligent suggestion about the code...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** by including a [mcve]. See also [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry guys, this is first time being here and asking a question in a blog and on top of that not-native english speaker. 
It is basically optimising the positions for accuracy based on tradable cash and other values. 
Thanks Idle_Mind for formatting my code. When I tried to do the same it threw some kind of error.

Comment: To start with, I'm converting a java project to .net. As part of it, loading the rest api cache with funds and positions. The above code I posted is optimizing the positions for accuracy (all this is a surface calculation in business layer) to display these to a trader. I'm new to this business and still learning. This code block itself is taking 15 mins in C# where java was just 2 to 3 mins.

Comment: And I put a timer, this calculation starts at 10:23 am and ends at 10:45 am. Which is almost 20 mins, should i use TPL to run this in a background task so it would't affect API loading time. 
If i comment this optimization part - loading time of API is 5 mins.
If I uncomment this , it is taking extra 20 mins to load the API which is now 25 mins just to load API.